# Liquid (Coda) Slider Height Not Adjusting

Tags: jquery, slider, height, responsive-design

I am using the [Liquid Slider](http://liquidslider.kevinbatdorf.com/) (responsive version of Coda Slider) for my portfolio site.

One of the slides is a list of projects/clients. When the user clicks one, they stay in the same slide but the list is swapped out with project details. My thought was to reduce load time by having the content of that slide be swapped out with another HTML page / div brought in by AJAX.

The problem is the height does not adjust for the new content. If you go forward one slide and then back, the height adjusts. If you adjust the window size, the height adjusts.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $("#dc3").click(function (){
            $(".clientlist").hide().load('dc3.html').fadeIn('slow');
        });
});
```

That worked for swapping the content, but not for adjusting the height. I tried using the height of the replacement div to set the height:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $("#dc3").click(function (){
            $(".clientlist").hide().load('dc3.html').fadeIn('slow');
            $(".liquid-slider").css({'height':($("#content").height()+'px')});
        });
});
```

But that didn't work either...

I am able to manually set a height, but I would prefer to have the height adjust automatically. There are a few adjustHeight functions in the slider script, but I am not sure how to call that when the content is swapped out.

The staging area for the site is [here](http://austingriffithphoto.com/newsite).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to call internal functions from outside the slider. You would want to call the adjustHeight() or adjustHeightNoAnimation() function in your ajax callback. See if this tutorial answers your question, and if not feel free to send me an email from the contact form on the LS website.

http://liquidslider.kevinbatdorf.com/tutorials/dynamically-add-content-to-a-panel-when-clicked-using-ajax/

Comment: Having the same problem, but adjustHeight() doesn't do anything at all, adjustHeightNoAnimation() doesn't exist and your link doesn't work... Someone else got an idea, even if this post is 2 years old?